# How to replace current string line with another line in vim?

Tags: vim, replace, edit, vi

I'd like to replace current string line with another (for example the another line is placed in 5 lines above current line). I can do it with a pair of commands

```
dd
:-5t-1
```

Is there the shorter way to obtain same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a plugin, my [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) offers a `]r` command (and many more):

> ]r            Fetch the line [count] visible lines above the current line and replace the current line with it.

With it, your example would be the short and easy `5]r`

---

In addition, the companion [LineJugglerCommands plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4465) now offers a similar `:Replace` Ex command. Again, your example would be

```
:Replace -5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dd
:-5t-1
```

is already pretty short if you ask me. But you can squeeze everything into a one-liner:

```
:d|-5t-1
```

and remove the `1` because it's implied by `-`:

```
:d|-5t-
```

Barring making a custom command or mapping I don't see how you could make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
:-5y<CR>Vp
```

is it shorter?

if you need do that really often, add this into your vimrc:

```
command! -range R d|<line1>,<line2>t-
```

then you can just do `:-5R` replace current line with `-5` line

or `2,4R` to cp line 2-4 (3 lines) to current line, and replace current line.